# How to find the service or the process that faced [UFW BLOCK]

Tags: networking, server, firewall, process, ufw

I spent my whole day trying to find an answer for my problem but no luck, so I decided to write here. I am not an expert in Linux, so pardon if my question is dumb. I saw the following message in my `/var/log/syslog`  :

`applications kernel: [24592.875919] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=ens18 SRC=192.168.1.100 DST=91.189.89.199 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=36213 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=33338 DPT=123 LEN=56`

where 192.168.1.100 is my server's IP address. Note that I defined the UFW rules so no outgoing or incoming port is open unless it's absolutely necessary, so such request being blocked is the right action. Now my guess is that there is a malicious file somewhere in my server that triggers this every 30 minutes or so (that's how often it is shown in the logs) however, the Destination IP and SPT are different in every try.
Now I would like to find the executable file / process / or whatever that causes this message but so far no luck!

I would appreciate any help from your side.

Comment: Note the destination IP 91.189.89.199 is owned by Canonical (makers of Ubuntu) so this is likely your system phoning home for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example blocked packet, the key indicator is the destination port, 123. That is the network time protocol port. And so the hint is that the service is NTP, which Ubuntu does run. The second indicator is the destination address which looks up as `golem.canonical.com`, which I assume is the Ubuntu NTP host. Actually, doiing a reverse lookup for `ntp.ubuntu.com` gives the same IP, so it has some alias':

```
$ nslookup ntp.ubuntu.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ntp.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.89.198
Name:   ntp.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.89.199
Name:   ntp.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.94.4
Name:   ntp.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.157
```

Therefore the service is NTP.

Check via (this example is on a server, maybe desktops are the same):

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-08-19 15:22:05 PDT; 16h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 640 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18892)
     Memory: 1.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─640 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Aug 19 15:22:05 s18 systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 19 15:22:05 s18 systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 19 15:22:11 s18 systemd-timesyncd[640]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 19 15:22:11 s18 systemd-timesyncd[640]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

While mine is working, yours will have failed to sync because you blocked the packets.

Comment: Well you saved me. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to check the destination port! Thank you very much.